# NMinimize stops using CPU but still evaluating

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a problem where I launch this code in NMinimize and after a minute, the CPU usage of Mathematica drops to 0. The notebook still shows as evaluating.

Here's some context and explanation of my code. I am trying to fit the accuracy data obtained from a cognitive task. I first show `l` letters to a participant, then another set of `l` letters out of which `d` are different from the first set of letters. For example, showing ABCD followed by AECF is `l = 4, d = 2`. Participants answer "same" if they think all the letters match, and "different" if at least 1 letter mismatches.

Matching letters are encoded as 1 and mismatching letters as -1. If all letters are considered to be matching, then the sum of all letters will be `l` and the participant will answer "same". This will result in a correct answer when `d = 0`. Conversely, if the total is not `l`, then the participant will answer "different", which is a correct answer if `d > 0`.

I'm testing whether noise during different steps of the cognitive process could explain the accuracy of participants. My function has 4 parameters, each indicating a probability that noise will interfere (real numbers between 0 and 1). After making sure NMinimize does not use invalid values (constraints don't work as "hard constraints"), I compute the expected accuracies for all types of trials with up to 4 letters (a total of 14 conditions). I then give the result of my objective function, which is how far from the real data each calculated accuracy is, plus a penalty that favorizes smaller differences at the cost of a larger global offset.

```
Clear[fNumericalToFit]
fNumericalToFit[Pe_Real, Pt_Real, Prs_Real, Prd_Real, iN_Integer: 10000] :=

Block[{bProbTotal,bMAsM,bMAsD,bNormalAnswer,bAcc,bErrMism,bErrMatch,bScore},

(* Verify that NMinimize does not use invalid values *)
bProbTotal = Total[Which[
    # < 0, -100*#,
    # > 0.2, 100*(# - 0.2),
    True, 0] & /@ {Pe, Pt, Prs, Prd}];

If[bProbTotal > 0, Return[bProbTotal]];

bMAsM = (1 - Pe)*(1 - Pt) + Pe*Pt; (* Prob of a match being interpreted as match *)
bMAsD = (1 - Pe)*Pt + Pe*(1 - Pt); (* Prob of a match being interpreted as mismatch *)
bNormalAnswer = (1 - Prs - Prd); (* Prob of not making a biased answer *)

bAcc = ParallelTable[
    Which[
        d == 0, 
        bErrMatch = RandomChoice[{bMAsM, bMAsD} -> {1, -1}, {iN, l}].ConstantArray[1, l];
        (Count[bErrMatch, l]/iN)*bNormalAnswer + Prs,

        d == l,
        bErrMism = RandomChoice[{1 - Pt, Pt} -> {1, -1}, {iN, d}].ConstantArray[-1,d];
        (1 - Count[bErrMism, l]/iN)*bNormalAnswer + Prd,

        True,
        bErrMism = RandomChoice[{1 - Pt, Pt} -> {1, -1}, {iN, d}].ConstantArray[-1,d];
        bErrMatch = RandomChoice[{bMAsM, bMAsD} -> {1, -1}, {iN,l - d}].ConstantArray[1, l - d];
        (1 - Count[bErrMism + bErrMatch, l]/iN)*bNormalAnswer + Prd],
    {l, 4}, {d, 0, l}];

  bScore = Abs[Flatten[bAcc] - {0.97`, 0.971`, 0.96`, 0.955`, 0.975`, 0.955`, 0.909`, 0.97`, 0.975`, 0.947`, 0.785`, 0.945`, 0.973`, 0.983`}];
  Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore]
  ]
```

Does anyone have a clue why running this function in NMinimize results in not using any CPU after a minute while still evaluating?

```
NMinimize[fNumericalToFit[EncodeErr,TestErr,RespSame,RespDiff],{EncodeErr,TestErr,RespSame,RespDiff}]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I copied and paste the code and tried to run it. I got a result back. I'll clarify to include the code that leads to my problem though!

Comment: When your code does not hang, it appears to be minimizing `bProbTotal` rather than `bScore `.

Comment: That is weird... Can you tell me how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: `bProbTotal` is given by `Total[Which[# < 0, -100*#, # > 0.2, 100*(# - 0.2), True, 0] & /@ {0.20000000000965154, 0.07745625850428044, 
   0.03822638935911683, 0.019227848497057474}]` for the solution given by @MarcoB and is equal to `9.65153*10^-10`, which is greater than `0`, triggering the `Return` statement.  `ParallelTable`, when it works, behaves similarly.

Comment: Also, I ran the calculation, printing every evaluation of `bScore`.  It had values of order `3`, and then the calculation returned an answer of `3.16211*10^-9`, which could only have come from `bProbTotal`.

Comment: If you still are interested in the question, I can (1) eliminate the `Return[bProbTotal]` problem and simplify the code, and (2) obtain a largely symbolic answer to the problem in the limit of large `iN`, although not until next weekend.  So, are you interested?  Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with `ParallelTable` replaced by `Table`, as suggested by [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob), the code in the question has two significant issues.

- First, `fNumericalToFit` returns `bProbTotal` or `bScore`, depending on its input parameters, and the values of these two quantities typically are quite different.  Depending on what region of parameter space `NMinimize` begins in, it will minimize one or the other of `bProbTotal` or `Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore]`.  It happens that, for the code as written, it attempts to minimize `bProbTotal`, which is not the desired quantity.
- Second, if `NMinimize` does try to minimize `Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore]`, it cannot converge, because the evaluation of `bScore` involves random numbers, which change from one call to the next.  It can, however, obtain a rough minimum in some cases.

To illustrate the first issue, replace `If[bProbTotal > 0, Return[bProbTotal]]` by `If[bProbTotal > 0, Sow[bProbTotal, bP]; Return[bProbTotal]]`, and `Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore]` by `Sow[Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore], bS]` in order to distinguish between the two paths by which `fNumericalToFit` can return.  Then, compute

```
tst = Reap[NMinimize[fNumericalToFit[EncodeErr, TestErr, RespSame, RespDiff], 
    {EncodeErr, TestErr, RespSame, RespDiff}], {bP, bS}]; tst // First
(* {3.39165*10^-10, {EncodeErr -> 0.2, TestErr -> 0.0774563, 
                     RespSame -> 0.0382264, RespDiff -> 0.0192278}} *)
```

Now look at the final 40 values returned by `bProbTotal`.

```
tst[[2, 1, 1, -40 ;;]]
(* {1.49046*10^-6, 3.3919*10^-10, 3.3919*10^-10, 3.3919*10^-10, 
    1.06634*10^-6, 3.39179*10^-10, 3.39179*10^-10, 1.49046*10^-6, 
    3.39179*10^-10, 3.39179*10^-10, 3.39179*10^-10, 3.3917*10^-10, 
    3.3917*10^-10, 1.49046*10^-6, 3.3917*10^-10, 3.3917*10^-10, 
    3.3917*10^-10, 1.2784*10^-6, 3.39168*10^-10, 3.39168*10^-10, 
    1.49046*10^-6, 3.39168*10^-10, 3.39168*10^-10, 3.39168*10^-10, 
    3.39165*10^-10, 3.39165*10^-10, 1.49046*10^-6, 3.39165*10^-10, 
    3.39165*10^-10, 3.39165*10^-10, 1.38443*10^-6, 3.39165*10^-10, 
    3.39165*10^-10, 1.49046*10^-6, 3.39165*10^-10, 3.39165*10^-10, 
    3.39165*10^-10, 3.39165*10^-10, 1.83437*10^-9, 3.39165*10^-10} *)
```

In contrast, the final 40 values returned by `Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore]` are

```
tst[[2, 2, 1, -40 ;;]]
(* {3.33007, 3.31574, 3.30547, 3.3116, 3.31537, 3.30142, 3.3148, 3.2837, 3.36089, 
    3.31254, 3.3148, 3.30792, 3.31537, 3.32385, 3.34129, 3.32441, 3.32347, 
    3.32498, 3.31961, 3.34006, 3.32064, 3.32998, 3.31433, 3.32168, 3.33375, 
    3.30208, 3.32441, 3.33874, 3.31442, 3.29454, 3.32932, 3.3164, 3.32017, 
    3.29623, 3.30406, 3.33139, 3.3312, 3.31942, 3.31537, 3.346} *)
```

Evidently, `NMinimize` has minimized `bProbTotal`.

One way to minimize the desired quantity is to penalize `bProbTotal` values by `Return[10^5 bProbTotal]` instead of `Return[bProbTotal]`.  The resulting computation is much slower but finally returns

```
{0.664027, {EncodeErr -> 0.000252496, TestErr -> 0.0106023, 
            RespSame -> 0.0297825, RespDiff -> 0.0190421}}
```

along with the warning,

> NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

The final 40 values returned by `Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore]` now are

```
(* {0.656203, 0.65411, 0.65725, 0.657821, 0.662563, 0.657154, 0.661722, 0.655251, 
    0.654094, 0.660295, 0.650668, 0.656393, 0.653142, 0.661802, 0.655046, 0.654395, 
    0.659994, 0.659343, 0.661342, 0.660184, 0.656488, 0.652096, 0.662389, 0.658964, 
    0.653825, 0.657917, 0.660675, 0.655426, 0.652302, 0.652952, 0.65449, 0.65078, 
    0.652968, 0.658488, 0.656473, 0.655654, 0.658677, 0.653729, 0.65366, 0.665608} *)
```

all hovering about `0.664027`, the poorly converged solution returned by `NMinimize`.  It is informative to evaluate `fNumericalToFit` for the final parameters also returned by `NMinimize`.

```
fNumericalToFit @@ Values[tst[[1, 2]]]
(* 0.654389 *)
```

close to `0.664027`.  In fact, if this last line of code is executed repeatedly, it yields a different value close to `0.664027` each time.  This is not surprising, because, as already noted, the calculation of `bScore` involves random numbers.

In summary, to obtain an approximate minimum for `Total[bScore] + 2*Max[bScore]`, severely penalize any values of `bProbTotal` returned by `fNumericalToFit`.

The original question posed was, of course, why does `ParallelTable` sometimes not work, whereas `Table` does.  This question probably cannot be resolved without knowing the internal working of `NMinimize`.  Certainly, using `ParallelTable` changes the order in which table elements are computed, and therefore changes what random numbers are used to compute those elements.  In closing, I would remark that `Table` is more efficient than `RandomTable` for this problem, by as much as a factor of two.  I determined this by observing CPU usage on my PC.  Also, `NMinimize`, left to its own devices, performs a degree of parallelization on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I did observe a behavior similar to the one you described with your definitions (i.e. CPU sitting idle while calculation continued).

However, I found that changing `ParallelTable` to a simple `Table` in the definition of your function seems to fix whatever problem you had. I did not spend enough time on it to figure out *why* there was a problem. Perhaps the distribution of definitions to parallel kernels was incomplete?

Anyway, when applying the `ParallelTable` -> `Table` substitution in your code (and instrumenting the minimization function to see it run and collect the intermediate results):

```
e = 0; s = 0;
Row[{"Evaluation = ", Dynamic[e], "    ", "Steps = ", Dynamic[s]}]

results = 
  Reap@
   NMinimize[
     fNumericalToFit[EncodeErr, TestErr, RespSame, RespDiff], 
     {EncodeErr, TestErr, RespSame, RespDiff},
     EvaluationMonitor :> e++,
     StepMonitor :> (s++; Sow[{EncodeErr, TestErr, RespSame, RespDiff}])
   ];
```

[image]

The calculation terminated in less than a minute and I obtained:

```
results[[1]]

(* Out: {3.52701*10^-9, {EncodeErr -> 0.2, TestErr -> 0.0774563, 
                         RespSame -> 0.0382264, RespDiff -> 0.0192278}} *)
```

Comment: Even with `ParallelTable`, I obtain results in about a minute, `{5.49044*10^-10, {EncodeErr -> 0.0476947, TestErr -> 0.056123, 
  RespSame -> 0.18237, RespDiff -> 0.2}}`.  The work load across the four processors on my PC was extremely nonuniform,, explaining why little improvement in speed occurred.

Comment: Interestingly, with `Table` I obtain different results, `{3.46628*10^-9, {EncodeErr -> 0.2, TestErr -> 0.0774563, RespSame -> 0.0382264, RespDiff -> 0.0192278}}`, suggesting an error in the code.  Also interestingly, the `Table` calculation used about 2/3 of my CPU power, indicating that `NMinimize` must have used multiple processors even without being instructed to.

Comment: So, I ran with `ParallelTable` again, and the calculation ground to a halt without terminating.  So, I closed Mathematica and then started it from scratch, and it worked fine, although it produced different results than those in my first comment.  Then, with the same kernels, I again ran the problem and it ground to a halt without terminating.

Comment: Finally, I ran the code with `Table` several times to be sure that it was not failing on the second or third run.  It did not.  Probably, the code with `ParallelTable` is overwriting something.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The `ParallelTable` version gave me similar results, i.e. it would stop using CPU power and just sit, CPU idle, without terminating. I had it happen multiple times, but could not reproduce it consistently, so I had suspected a sensitivity of the system to the choice of initial parameter values by `NMinimize`.

Comment: I found that using smaller values of `iN` also made it much less likely that the problem would occur when using `ParallelTable`. Thanks a lot for investigating this! I'm not marking your answer as a solution yet because it's not an explanation and we don't know precisely what's going on. But that helped out a lot!